# ETW provider for "Window in Focus" graph in Windows Performance Analyser

Tags: etw, xperf

Windows Performance Analyser has a graph called "Window in Focus". What provider/trace flag should I specify in xperf command line to get such a graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Window in Focus" information is provided by Microsoft-Windows-Win32k provider. For example:

```
xperf -start uisession -on Microsoft-Windows-Win32k
```

Comment: Consider specifying a flag to reduce the event rate. See this UIforETW change for details:
https://github.com/google/UIforETW/commit/9f1a9e7fc2fe6be11dbde92d064b3e58bef479bd

Answer (score 0):

I use this, which also captures the required data:

```
xperf -start perf!GeneralProfiles.InBuffer && timeout -1 && xperf -stop perf!GeneralProfiles.InBuffer Trace.etl
```

This captures most data you need.